# Correct configuration for using REL in Tridion Dynamic Component Presentations

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011, rel, tridion-content-delivery

We have a Dynamic CT to render the component output, in it there is a Component Link with link text. While previewing, the output appears to be correct but once we publish the page and hit, the link is not displayed (even the link text).
Both the output format of DCT and the target language has been set as REL but our tcdl:link are not resolved and dynamic component presentations are not rendered. Embedded presentations are getting rendered with page without resolving the tcdl:link tag. 
The storage file is pointing to sql db.

Could you pls advise on what else needs to be done?

Comment: Although Will is trying admirably to answer you, I'd simply suggest to have a look at your content delivery log files. Set the logging level to debug and simply trace the steps from the Deployer that writes the DCPs to the broker DB, to the web application that retrieves the DCP from the broker DB and executes the Component Link. Going there will help you more than anyone can do here in a Q&A format.

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps you can edit your question title to be a bit more specific. I assume that you want to have dynamic links resolved in Dynamic Component Presentations using REL. It sounds like you have set things up correctly, but just to make sure this is a quick check list:

1. You are using Tridion 2011 SP1 (dynamic links in REL DCPs do not resolve in 2011 GA)
2. The component template output format is REL, and it is set to be dynamic (note the publication target language does not have to be REL)
3. The component template outputs a component link

Publish a page containing a dynamic component presentation. Check the following:

1. In the published page content you should see something like `<tridion:ComponentPresentation ..../>` where the DCP will be inserted
2. In the database you should see your REL DCP in the `COMPONENT_PRESENTATIONS` table, this should contain `<tcdl:Link...>` tag where the link should be

Request the page in the browser. Check that the component presentation is displayed and the link is rendered into an `<a../>` anchor tag

If not, check the content delivery log files, to see if there are any errors. Also please check that dynamic linking is working on 'normal' pages.

Comment: We have checked the COMPONENT_PRESENTATIONS table in the db for the html of the DCP and found that the Span tag is coming as empty inside the <tcdl:Link...> which implies that the deployer is unable to send anything in the db, and so we started analyzing the cd_deployer_config.xml file There the license line was commented out. Could this be a reason?

Comment: If the license was the problem, nothing would be written to DB. Check your "Template Output Format" for your DCP, chances are it's set to HTML or Text. It should be REL

Comment: Sounds like a templating problem - if you can - try inserting some content into <tcdl:Link> tag (by updating the row in the DB) and see if the link gets rendered then... If it does, then you just need to find out why your templates are rendering an empty link...

Comment: The "Template Output Format" has been set to REL and the target language is "ASP.NET". Now when we hit the page following error comes..."Could not initialize class com.tridion.tcdl.tcdlprocessor"

Comment: Can you list all the cd*.jar files you have in bin/lib (or in the lib sub-directory from your TRIDION_HOME environment variable). Maybe you are missing cd_tcdl.jar or another jar

Comment: We have checked and cd_tcdl.jar exists.

Comment: So what error does it show in the log files?